# Domain entity/object and injecting services into it feels plain wrong, is there a justification?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, inversion-of-control, software-design

In my mind it feels like we need an inversion of construction here.

The entity is relying upon services to populate various properties, within itself.  This should be palmed off to a builder, shouldn't it? (That is the construction of the object) I'm looking at legacy code and performing some general refactoring.

In essence the entity should be pretty dumb, there seems to be mix of processing going on it that Im pretty certain should/could be broken out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Injecting services into domain entities might not be a good idea, but maybe not for the reason you think.

> In essence the entity should be pretty dumb, there seems to be mix of
>   processing going on it that Im pretty certain should/could be broken
>   out.

It's a controversial matter, but many believe that dumb domain entities is an anti-pattern ([Anemic Domain Model](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html)) and goes against the object oriented style of programming. Entities should not just contain data but also encapsulate behavior.

The problem is, how much behavior can you add before your domain object starts suffering low [cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29) ? In your example, relying upon services to populate various properties is a typical borderline case between what is the domain object's responsibility (cohesive) and what isn't. In addition, if the properties are explicitely loaded from a database, this might be a violation of the [persistence ignorance](http://thinkddd.com/glossary/persistence-ignorance/) principle.

If it turns out that these properties need to be initialized right from the birth of the object, I agree with you that a Factory or a Builder could be a better place to fetch that data and assemble the entity, especially if the construction logic is complex.

But usually, such a mechanism is there to provide lazy loading, in other words to populate the properties on-demand and just in time. This allows to defer costly operations such as fetching potentially big data from a database and avoids having a big object graph loaded in memory right from the start.

While I personally wouldn't be offended to see Services injected in entities at construction time for lazy loading purposes, some consider it bad practice : see [here](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/04/14/injecting-services-into-entities/) and [here](http://thinkbeforecoding.com/post/2009/03/04/How-not-to-inject-services-in-entities). You might prefer to use method injection or [delegate injection](http://thinkbeforecoding.com/post/2009/02/07/Lazy-load-and-persistence-ignorance) for cleaner, more testable entities.

Comment: its a small world (reference the delegate injection link, seen that on more than one occasion!). I get what you're saying about dumb versus encapsulation. The object graph 'is' loaded on demand and requires bootstrapping from a database (think a form definition and associated rules), but some ignorance is maintained as the services shield us from where this info is coming from directly i.e via business services utilising data services (relying upon what amounts to a repository ultimately)

Comment: I pulled out the construction into a builder,  using a factory for the builders serves me well.  Building can take place without completely stripping the entity of its ability to control its behaviour.